# Получить последние значения в строке

Tags: php

Есть строка `167_319_838_852` строка динамическая может быть такой `167_319_8388` и такой `167_3195`.

Подскажите как можно получить последние данные в строке `167_319_838_852` нужно `852` ?

Comment: `echo end(explode('_', $string));`

Comment: echo array_pop(explode('_', $string));

Comment: `array_slice(explode('_', $string),-1);` ещё можно (но надо учитывать что вернётся новый массив с последним эл-том старого). При работе с `array_pop()`, стоит знать, что она  вырезает этот эл-т с массива

Comment: Спасибо за помощь